# How to use double quotes + subString

Tags: java, xml, substring

I have a little problem. I parse an XML file to String and in the string, I must search phrase `id="t2"`, bellow I use `subString` - `indexOf`, but when I use double quotes by `"<text id=\"t2\" "` the program  throw exception and when I use simple quotes 
`"<text id=t2 "` - throw exception because phrase doesn't exists

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin -1, end 16319, length 21524
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at Parser.Test.main(Test.java:36)`

This is my code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory domFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = domFact.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(args[0]);
    DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(domSource, result);
    //System.out.println("XML IN String format is: \n" + writer.toString());
    String test = writer.toString();

    //String b = "<alt-trans id=\"t2\" ";

    String a = writer.toString().substring(writer.toString().indexOf("<alt-trans id=\"t2\" "), 
    writer.toString().indexOf("</alt-trans>"));

    System.out.println(a);
```

In the end result, the user will have to input id, like that

`String variable = scan.next();
 e.g. my variable = t4`

In program: `"<alt-trans id=\"variable\" "`

I don't know, how I can do it, anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest you use your debugger to check the exact value of `test` after it's assigned.  If it really does contain `<alt-trans id="t2"` then the code you've written will find it.

Comment: According to what you posted, this part of your code is returning -1 (minus one): `writer.toString().indexOf("<alt-trans id=\"t2\" ")` Are you sure that string actually appears in the file you are parsing? What is the encoding of that file? Is it UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: What should be the outcome of your program? XML string like `"<alt-trans id=\"variable\" "`?

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Yes, String have it what i looking for.
 Yes, it is UTF-8 
Program outcome should by part of String. 

When I input indexOf("<text id=") it run but in String I have several tag with <text id..> so i must have access to id